# WavesurferJS in a VueJS app, audio can be played but waveform never loads on IOS Safari?

Tags: ios, vue.js, audio, wavesurfer.js

I'm using WavesurferJS in my VueJS application, and i've been trying to solve this issue for the past week. On IOS Safari (and IOS Safari only, as far as i can tell), my wavesurfer component can't finish decoding the audio/loading the waveform, and a thin straight line just shows up. Without using `backend: "MediaElement"`, the component just shows up blank. Using the backend however, i can play the audio, but the waveform still never loads.

I read into the wavesurfer doc a bit and according the the **FAQ: "if you use the backend: 'MediaElement' option... The audio will start playing as you press play. A thin line will be displayed until the whole audio file is downloaded and decoded to draw the waveform.".** This is exactly what i'm experiencing, audio can be played and a thin line shows up, but i assume waveform never finishes downloading/decoding.

My Vue method that handles audio loading:

```
setupRecentRecordingandSave(data, num, name) {

  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

  if (this.wavesurfer[num] == null) {
    this.createWaveSurfer(num);
    this.wavesurfer[num].load(url);
    this.showRecent = true;
  } else {
    this.wavesurfer[num].load(url);
  }
  this.$store.commit("addCough", { key: name, val: data});
}
```

I'm using an array of wavesurfer elements, this method is called after a recording is made by the user, and the blob data is sent to this method.

My create wavesurfer code:

```
createWaveSurfer(num) {
  Vue.set(
    this.wavesurfer,
    num,
    WaveSurfer.create({
      container: "#waveform-" + num,
      waveColor: "#f7931e",
      progressColor: "#824500",
      fillParent: true,
      hideScrollbar: true,
      backend: "MediaElement"
    })
  );
},
```

I've been struggling with this for a while now, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue wasn't with WaveSurfer, but with the way i was recording user audio on IOS. After fixing and making sure the audio recorded properly, the waveform displayed correctly.

Comment: How do you able to record audio on IOS, i need some help as mediaRecorder is not supported in safari, can you please share your thoughts here, it would be helpful, thanks

Comment: @AbhiThakkar, i ended up using [this](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill) polyfill, which allows for audio recording on mobile safari, however as far as i know, there isn't a solution for being able to record audio on IOS chrome.

Comment: I am trying to add this pollyfill package into my vue.js project but I am getting "TypeError: MediaRecorder is not a constructor" error after integrating it. I have added pollyfill like this on mounted method. window.MediaRecorder = require('audio-recorder-polyfill');

Comment: I'm not too sure what your problem is, but for me, i imported the polyfill , and did "window.MediaRecorder = AudioRecorder", where AudioRecorder is the imported polyfill. Afterwards i was able to use MediaRecorder as i normally would.